# discord.js - How to get random user ID's of users with reaction

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to get random user ID from users with reaction on specific message.

```js
    await msg.react("<:SenkoSad:788848057844367411>")
    setTimeout(()=> {
        const winner = msg.reactions.cache.get("<:SenkoSad:788848057844367411>").users.cache.random().id
        message.channel.send(`Random user from emotes: <@${winner}>`)
    }, time-Date.now())
```

Here is error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users')`
on line `const winner = msg.reactions.cache.get("<:SenkoSad:788848057844367411>").users.cache.random().id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used @Teyrox's code but when time is out and I've reacted to message then bot says "No winner" but that's not true.

```js
if (msg.reactions.cache.get("788848057844367411").users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size > 0) {
    const winner = msg.reactions.cache.get("788848057844367411").users.cache.filter(user => !user.client).random().id
    client.channels.cache.get(args[0]).send(`Winner: @<${winner}>`)
} else {
    client.channels.cache.get(args[0]).send("No winner.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the line to:

```
const winner = msg.reactions.cache.get("788848057844367411").users.cache.random().id
```

I am not entirely sure, but perhaps `get()` expects a `Snowflake` for a custom emoji rather than the format you provided.

Comment: It works, but every time when Im trying to get "winner" result ID is bot's ID

Comment: Has anyone else reacted to the message? If the bot has the only reaction, the bot will be the only possible winner.

Comment: Yes, two other users reacted to message

Answer (score 1):

Try using [@metro's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15818349/metro) answer but use the [filter](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) function

Like:

```js
msg.reactions.cache.get("788848057844367411").users.cache.filter(e => !e.bot).random().id
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

Comment: That could mean that there were no other reactions besides the bot's reaction

Answer (score 0):

By using [`reactions.cache.get("788848057844367411")`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ReactionManager?scrollTo=cache) you are getting a [MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageReaction).

**Note that to get a reaction you need to provide a unicode emoji** (In case they are default emojis) **or an ID** (In this case it is 78884805784444367411, only the ID, not the emoji name).

[`MessageReaction.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=users) returns you a [ReactionsUserManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ReactionUserManager), the cache of this includes ALL users who have reacted to this message including the bot itself, so you should add a Filter: `.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot)`

As for the error, what you can do to avoid this error is a conditional where you check if the number of users (not counting the bot) is greater than 0.

```js
if(msg.reactions.cache.get("788848057844367411").users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size > 0) {
    // If there can be a winner
} else {
    // If nobody reacted
}
```

Comment: It always shows that nobody reacted, even with reactions from 3 users.